# How to Create budget table Using current Actual Table

Tags: sql-server, ssas-2012

I have  Fact table with 6 metric columns and three date key columns remain all are foreign keys,I need design  a Budget table based on that fact table like

1)Current year Budget =last year fact +10%(last year fact)

2)Current Quarter Budget =last Quarter fact +10%(last Quarter fact)

3)Current Month Budget =last Month  fact +10%(last Month fact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this pseudocode make any sense?

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()),
    YearFact * 1.1 AS YearBudget,
    QuarterFact * 1.1 AS QuarterBudget,
    MonthFact * 1.1 AS MonthBudget
FROM
    FactTable
WHERE
    DATEPART(YEAR, FactDate) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - 1;
```

Comment: Hi Sean, Its Make Sense for year wise ,But I don't have the yearly fact ,quarterly fact and monthly fact separately I have fact as one column with date key .

Comment: I Have fact table like exactly  AdevtureWork database "FactInternetsale" fact table .